# Error when installing python26 on RedHat Enterprise Server 5.5

Tags: python, linux, gitlab, redhat

I'm trying to install GitLab community edition on a Linux server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5) using following tutorial.

[Installing GitLab on RedHat Enterprise 5 RHEL 5](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/installing-gitlab-on-redhat-enterprise-5-rhel-5.html)

But when I try to install python26 as per the tutorial, I'm getting following error.

```
# yum install python26
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
No package python26 available.
Nothing to do
```

I have some experience with Ubuntu, but I'm new to Red Hat. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: what is the putput of `yum list python26` ?

Comment: "This system is not registered with RHN." Come back when it is.

Comment: @SandeepLade  `Error: No matching Packages to list`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What it means? Should I get registered with so called "RHN"

Comment: Only if you want access to the packages and updates.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How can I do it? Is there any special requirements? I'm trying to install it on one of my workplace machine.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/en/store/red-hat-enterprise-linux-server#?sku=RH00005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not registered with RHN, you can use alternative Repository for install this package. One such repository is geekymedia.com centos repository.

To add repository to your system,

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://mirrors.geekymedia.com/centos/geekymedia.repo
```

To install python26 package,

```
yum install python26
unlink /usr/bin/python2
cd /usr/bin/
ln -s python26 python2
```